# Where is Bake sound to F-curve in 4.0?

Tags: animation, baking, audio, graph-editor, fcurves

It`s not grey out, I litterally cant see it. I was looking in Key and Channel tab, and theres no sound option. Did they move it again somewhere or got rid of it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is still found under *Channel* in the *Graph Editor* but it is now called *Sound to Samples*. It still needs an existing channel/key to create the curve, i.e. to not be greyed out.

Comment: awesome thanks!