# Bake sound to F-curve missing from Graph Editor Channel menu

Tags: node-editor, baking, audio

I am trying to bake a sound to an F-curve as input to a Shader node. I follow the suggestions [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/304520/how-to-make-baked-sound-f-curve-trigger-a-layers-visibility) and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/299266/geometry-nodes-how-can-i-use-baked-sound-f-curve-data-as-a-math-function), but still I cannot make it work. I can add a keyframe to a value node, open the Graph Editor, and select the keyframe. But nothing like "Bake sound to F-curve" shows in the context menu:

[image: screenshot of missing "bake sound to f-curve"]

Here are the menu items I see under `Channel`:

```
Delete Channels
---
Group Channels
Ungroup Channels
---
Toggle Channel Setting
Enable Channel Setting
Disable Channel Setting
---
Toggle Channel Editability
Extrapolation Mode
---
Hide Selected Curves
Hide Unselected Curves
Reveal Curves
---
Expand Channels
Collapse Channels
---
Move...
---
Revive Disabled F-Curves
```

I am using Blender 3.3.2, and [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1XGZqidx4QIfjI0rFeS-MTQtfq2FNrc_X/view?usp=drive_link) is a link to the Blender file.

How can I make bake a sound to an F-curve if that option in the context menu is missing?

Comment: Please use the search function. Does this answer your question? [Where is Bake sound to F-curve in 4.0?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/305162/where-is-bake-sound-to-f-curve-in-4-0)

Comment: Oh, you are using an older version... in previous versions before 3.6 it can be found in the _Key_ menu, not the _Channel_ menu. If you are follwoing a tutorial, make sure the version there is the same as yours, some things change between versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Blender versions 3.5 and earlier *Bake Sound to F-Curves* is located in the *Key* menu of the *Graph Editor*:

[image: 3.5 and older]

In version 3.6 it changed to the *Channel* menu:

[image: 3.6]

In the new version 4.0 it is still in the *Channel* menu, but now it is called *Sound to Samples*:

[image: 4.0]